# get into a conda environment and sequentially execute a package with subprocess

Tags: python, bash, shell, subprocess

I want to get into a conda environment called 'tensor' and  execute a package call slither-analysis that I had installed in that environment and can only be execute from terminal.

I tried some things but nothing worked out:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run('conda activate tensor | slither . --checklist > analysis.md', capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)
```

The output is the following:

```
CompletedProcess(args=' conda activate CISmartContracts | slither . --checklist > analysis.md', returncode=255, stdout='', stderr='"slither" not recognized as internal or external command,\nprogram or executable batch file\n')
```

How can I activate an environment and execute a command package inside that environment with subprocess or any other recommended python library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real command in Windows is '&' and not '|' if you want to sequentally execute commands. In Unix is ';'. So the solution for me is:

```
subprocess.run('conda activate tensor & slither . --checklist > analysis.md', capture_output=True, text=True, shell=True)
```